# How do we prove the following set is measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I was reading the proof of Egorov Theorem in the Real Analysis Book of Elias M Stein

Suppose $\{f_k\}$ is a sequence of measurable functions defined on the measurable set $E$ with $m(E)< \infty$ and assuming that $f_k \rightarrow f $ a.e on $E$

Then the set ${E_k}^n=\{x\in E| \hspace{2 mm} |{f_j}(x)-f(x)|<1/n \hspace{1 mm} \forall j>k\} $

The proof assumes that is function is measurable. I have been trying to use the following definition to prove it, but I am stuck

A set $A$ is said to be lebesgue measurable if $\forall \epsilon>0 \hspace{1 mm} \exists$ an open set $O$ such that $A\subset O  $ such that $m_*(O-A)<\epsilon$ where $m_*$ is the exterior measure. 
I even tried thinking in terms of the equivalent definition of measurability using closed set but could not think of a way to prove it.
Can you guys help me figure it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one definition of a function being measurable.  We need that $\{x \mid f(x) > \alpha \} \in \Sigma$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$.  This implies that the preimage of any interval in $\mathbb{R}$ is measurable. (Do you understand why?)

At the beginning of the proof for this theorem, you can assume without loss of generality that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} f_{n}$ exists and equals $f(x)$ for all $x \in E$.

Then, since each $f_{n}$ is measurable, the limit of the sequence, $f$, is measurable.

Finally, if $g$ is measurable so is $-g$.  And if $f$, $g$ are measurable, so is $f + g$.  Also, if $g$ is measurable, so is $|g|$.  Using these properties, it's easy to see that $\{ x \in E \mid |f_{j} - f| < \frac{1}{n} \forall j \geq n \} = \bigcap \limits_{j = n}^{\infty} \{ x \in E \mid |f_{j} - f | < \frac{1}{n} \}$ is measurable, because it is the countable intersection of measurable sets.

Comment: Thank you. Because we were supposed to prove the measurability of a set , I was using that definition and didnt reason the way you did. It makes perfect sense. I am grateful.

Comment: You're welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

The important fact is that all $f_k$ are measurable. Hence, so is $f$. This implies that $|f_j - f|$ is also measurable.

By definition, this means that the inverse image of every interval (alternatively of every Borel subset of $\Bbb{R}$) is measurable.

Hence,

$$
E_k^n = \bigcap_{j>k} |f_j -f|^{-1}([0,1/n))
$$

is measurable as a countable intersection of measurable sets (recall that the class of measurable sets is a $\sigma$-algebra).

EDIT: General comment: Just as you would normally not try to show that e.g.

$$
x \mapsto \sin(e^{x^2} - \sin(x))
$$

is continuous by computing for every $\varepsilon > 0$ some $\delta > 0$ such that ..., it is often best to **not** used the **definition** of measurable sets, but to use closure properties of measurable sets only (countable intersections, unions, complements of measurable sets are measurable, measurable functions form a vector space, inverse images of Borel sets under measurable functions are measurable, limits of measurable functions are measurable, ...).

Comment: Thank you , your post was really helpful. I will keep this in mind next time